# Can't be mapped a specific URL by Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I've developed a Servlet which is mapped to URLs with the pattern as bellow.

```
urlPatterns = {"/dv/*" , "/dv/", "/dv*", "/dv/*/*"}
```

Everything is working like a charm, but i have a major problem with this URL
`http://localhost:6070/dv/test/MyProject?=&projectType=auto&{}`, because of existing character "{" or "}" in URL.
How can I deal with this problem?
My web container is Tomcat v8, and I can't avoid from this character in the URL since I'm trying to proxy
a third-party server, and I don't have access to modify the URLs before sending to the Servlet.

Comment: URL Encoding? Filters in front of the servlet? There is too little information to go on

Comment: If you are using [Apache as the reverse proxy to Tomcat](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/TomcatReverseProxy), you may try `.htaccess` [redirection](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/all/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-.htaccess-file).

Comment: @NicoVanBelle URL Encoding of the connector is "UTF-8"

Comment: I'm using a single instance of Tomcat, I checked the other pre-developed Servlets in my project, and all have the same problem when I add character "{" or "}" to my URL.

Comment: I think there is a problem which relates to my Tomcat.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle I didn't mention it, because there is no filter or anything else! you want me to post every line of codes for this simple problem!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
This problem boils down to Tomcat configuration; Therefore, I added `relaxedQueryChars` to my Tomcat's Connector tag, and my problem was solved, but the point is this attribute is just available in Tomcat 8.5.31 or later.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" maxPostSize="4194304" URIEncoding="UTF-8" bindOnInit="false" server="orca framework" relaxedQueryChars='[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;'/>
```